# SQL Mangement Studio/SQL: Seeing the GroupBy / Sum aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions, ssms

Quite new to this but i have created a SQL script that groups by and Sums a column.. but in SQL Management studio it shows me a grid with column value but nothing underneath it i.e. the SUM..

Do i have to configure SQL Management studio to show me the SUM or something..

Here is my query its very easy

```
    SELECT  RowNum ,
    ClientName ,
    ( SELECT    SUM(Amount) AS Expr1
    ) AS Amount
    FROM    #TempItems
    GROUP BY RowNum , Amount , ClientName
```

I also changed it to display TextView rather than GRIDVIEW but still no hope.

It displays the Amount column correctly but i don't see any SUM underneath it

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the subselect:

```
SELECT
    RowNum ,
    ClientName ,
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM #TempItems
GROUP BY RowNum, ClientName
```

Comment: or, as Mark has also changed, the `group by` on the Amount column

Comment: +1 - Also OP should notice you removed `Amount` from the group by, since it's an aggregate function and not needed in the grouping.

Comment: Thanks everyone for there comments, i have amended the query and it works but i still can't see the SUM in SQL Server Management Studio.. I basically get a matrix (rows and colunms) but NO extra field under Amount for the Sum of the amount

Answer (score 0):

Just happened onto this post...
The answer is to Martin's question is - WITH ROLLUP:

```
SELECT
    RowNum ,
    ClientName ,
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM #TempItems
GROUP BY RowNum, ClientName WITH ROLLUP
```

You'll get extra rows with NULL in the group by column for the subtotals, total.